# Ubuntu 12.04 - full disk encryption without alternate installer?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-encryption

Is there a way to have a full-disk encryption on Ubuntu without using alternate installer CD?

Comment: May I ask why are you refusing to use alternate installer CD?

Comment: @chmod Well, actually no reason, I'm just curious. Or... If you ask... I'm using DVD version of Ubuntu installation image. It has russian language by default and it's convenient to use it. Alternate has only English I suppose. And text GUI is ugly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think there is a convient checkbox "Full Disk Encryption, Y/N". However it is possible to get FDE b encrypting it inside the live environment, and then install as normal in the cryto-block device (approx: /dev/mapper/sda2_crypt). But that is painstaiking in my experience and even more inconvinient than the alternate CD.

Example:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsViaUbiquity